# Unhandled Exception type IOException in Class variables

Tags: java

I have a class where I am populating variable values as below

```
public class JSONDBWriter{

  // JDBC driver name, database URL, Database credentials
  private static final String JDBC_DRIVER = ReadPropertiesFile("JDBC_DRIVER");  
  private static final String DB_URL =  ReadPropertiesFile("DB_URL");  
  private static final String USER =  ReadPropertiesFile("USER");
  private static final String PASS =  ReadPropertiesFile("PASS");



  public static void main(String[] args) {
```

However, Java compiler is giving error "Unhandled Exception type IOException"
My ReadPropertiesFile throws IOException.

Comment: ReadPropertiesFile() is method and method's are not called directly into class. they need other method,constructor or block to call.

Comment: On what line does it throw that error?

Answer (score 3):

Use static initializer.

```
public class JSONDBWriter {
    public static String driver;

   static {
        try{
            driver = //...
        } catch (IOException e){
            //
        }
    }
    //other methods
}
```

If you want your variables to be **final**, try something like below:

```
public class Test {

    public static final String test = getDataNoException();

    private static String getData() throws IOException {
        return "hello";
    }

    private static String getDataNoException() {
        try {
            return getData();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "no data";
        }
    }
    //other methods
}
```

Comment: My variables are final